# 'OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded' after updating Google Play Services to 7.8.0

Tags: android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, google-play-services

I'm using following libraries in my project:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.8.4'
```

And after updating **Google Play Services** version from 7.5.0 to

> **com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0**

I started getting `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` when trying to run my app.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1913)
at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.intern(Prototype.java:95)
at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstBaseMethodRef.<init>(CstBaseMethodRef.java:50)
at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef.<init>(CstMethodRef.java:31)
at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:310)
at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

The error is 100% reproducible and it does not happen when using Google Play Services 7.5.0 so I'm pretty sure it is caused by the version update. Though, if the problem is in the library itself or my project setup, I don't know.

Does this happen to anybody else as well?

Comment: What's your build tool version

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I updated build tool (as well as compilSdkVersion) to 23.0.0

Comment: Are you using a `GoogleMap`?  There are at least two known memory leaks related to `GoogleMap`, only one of which has a workaround.

Comment: I am using some location services but not `GoogleMap` or `MapFragment` particularly.

Comment: Is there any actual size increase in your .apk after upgrading to the newer tools and Play Services?